# Use different versions of the same library in one app for different Android versions

Tags: java, android, gradle

In my Android app, I am using a library (which I do not control), and the latest version of this library uses java.io features that only became available in Android SDK version 33 (for example, InputStream.transferTo() method). I am not yet willing to raise the minSdkVersion of my app to 33, and I want to use the latest library whenever possible.
Is there a way to include two versions of the library into .AAB file, one for older versions of Android and one for newer versions of Android? If yes, how to set it up in gradle build files?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for two versions of Android app build `flavors` or `variants` are used:

```
    productFlavors {
        create("demo") {
            // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
            // If you are using only one dimension, this property is optional,
            // and the plugin automatically assigns all the module's flavors to
            // that dimension.
            dimension = "version"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix = "-demo"
        }
        create("full") {
            dimension = "version"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".full"
            versionNameSuffix = "-full"
        }
    }
```

[Ref. Android docs](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#dependencies)